# EF 6 Mix Mode Code First and DB First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Iam using EF 6 with database first .. and every time I update the scheme : all my editings to the edmx file  (mainly for defining db built in functions) are lost .. but using code first I can add my dbmodelbuilder calls in a separate  file with partial class .. and by that I can also use all the nuget packages that targets code first such as EntityFramework.Functions.
Thanks for helping

Comment: what is your question then ?

Comment: How to access to the DbModelBuilder while the DbModer being build from edmx files (ssdl,..others)

Comment: you can't. Those two approaches are completely different. Either you go from database and let the classes be defined for you (with default modelBuilder, as the classes will match the Db schema exactly), or you start with code and let the database let be created or modified for you, where you can use the modelBuilder as well to match the schema you wish.

Comment: for DB first to build the model from edmx files it must create a ModelBuilder to apply the configuration and definitions, what I ask if there any call backs to that ModuleBuilder either befor or after applying the configuration.

Comment: why should it? it just creates the classes to match the schema, as the modelBuilder is just to adjust the definitions if something differs. I don't really know what configuration you mean - if it's the DbEntitySetConfiguration, it isnt applied at compile time or context creation - it is when the database is queried the first time, right before the initializer is run.

Comment: It should because it takes a connection string containing metadata that provides a paths to the edmx files(csdl 'conceptual',ssdl 'storage', msdl 'metadata') model definition files

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Code First from database` option when you are creating your ADO.net entity data model. This will give you the code first classes that you can edit.

After creating your model you would need to stick to using the code first model otherwise you will need to regenerate your code-first after every database change...

Download the EF tools [here.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762)

Comment: I understand that .. but thats not related my question .. you should post this as comment not an answer.. sorry but this was a waste of time